# Java: Different objects in Interface's ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a superclass called Fighter. From Fighter there are the subclasses of Knight, Sorcerer, Troll, and Ogre. Sorcerer, Troll, and Ogre implement an interface called Enemy.

Enemy contains this ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Enemy> enemy = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

In my driver file, I am filling the ArrayList randomly with objects of type Sorcerer, Troll, and Ogre.

My problem is when I am trying to call methods of Types Sorcerer, Troll, and Ogre in the ArrayList.

Here is some code for an example:

```
while(javalot.getHealth() > 0)
        {
            int attack;
            for(Enemy i : Enemy.enemy)
            {
                attack = javalot.toFight();


                if(i instanceof Sorcerer)
                {   
                    System.out.println("Health " +((Sorcerer) i).getHealth());
                    ((Sorcerer) i).takeDamage(attack, sorcArmor, weapon);
                    System.out.println("Health " +((Sorcerer) i).getHealth());
                }
                else if(i instanceof Troll)
                {
                    System.out.println("Health" +((Troll) i).getHealth());
                    ((Troll) i).takeDamage(attack,trollArmor, weapon);
                    System.out.println("Health" +((Troll) i).getHealth());
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Health" +((Ogre) i).getHealth());
                    ((Ogre) i).takeDamage(attack, ogreArmor, weapon);
                    System.out.println("Health" +((Ogre) i).getHealth());
                }
            }


        }
```

My question is can I even use instanceof through an interface like this?

I am assuming no because what I am doing runs, but it is not outputting anything.

My next question is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Declaring any fields other than `static final` in an interface is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Alright, thank you for the information, is there any special reasoning to that?

Comment: Move `getHealth()` and `takeDamage` up to your interface level, and then you don't need any of this code.  All of those blocks are the same except for the class name, so refactor the methods up.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Alright, I see what you are saying and will do so. Thank you.

Comment: What purpose does the `Enemy` interface have?  Could this just be an `ArrayList<Fighter>`?  And are `getHealth` and `takeDamage` methods of the `Fighter` class?  If that's the case, you don't need any casting, and you certainly don't need to repeat everything three times over.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, the purpose of the Enemy interface is just something to say that these three classes are considered bad. And yes, getHealth and takeDamage are methods of the Fighter Class. Looking at it now, I see what I did was redundant and unnecessary. I was just looking for something to differentiate between my classes.

Comment: Well, one more option would be to have `Enemy` as a subclass of `Fighter`, and `Troll` and `Ogre` as subclasses of `Enemy`.  That has the benefit of coding in the information that all enemies are fighters.  Then you could keep this as an `ArrayList<Enemy>`, and still be able to call `getHealth` and `takeDamage` without casting, and without duplicating code.

Comment: @DavidWallace You're absolutely right and I thought about that for a second before I asked this question and I quickly dismissed it. I was just being stubborn and I ended up wasting time. Thanks for your help. It is greatly appreciated.